# Display Webcam In Java

Tags: java, webcam

I just started Java last week so I'm just getting the fundamentals down at the moment as I have a lot to learn (btw I'm using Eclipse on Ubuntu 11.04 if that helps). However I do a lot of screencasting, and I display my webcam in a lot of the videos that I do. So later on I would like to make a simple app that just displays the webcam. Not anything else.

So I'm asking this question now so not only will I remember what my goal is, but also so when I feel I'm ready, and confident to work on this I will know where to go.

I don't want any code, but a reference on where to go. I'd like to just use Java. Although one of my co workers told me to look into FMJ, and JMF. However not knowing what these are I assume their like add-ons for Java, but I'd like to just stick with Java alone if it's possible.

Additionally like I said I'm still new to Java, and am learning from thenewboston's tutorials on YouTube (Currently at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XqTg2buXS5o) so if you know of any other resources to help new Java programmers like myself, and others it'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have used [lti-civil](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lti-civil/), which seems to work quite well for video capture.

I have used it on Windows and linux, I have not tested it on Mac but it says it works there too.

It does not need to be preinstalled, as it is a jar and a dll/so which can be downloaded with the Java application, or run via a JNLP webstart which supports native libraries.

There are no 100% pure Java libraries that can capture video, so all the options (including JMF) require a native component (.dll or .so).

Comment: +1, this answer is bang on. You need to resort to native code somewhere to do this, and IMO it's best to avoid JMF (it's old and dead) and FMJ too (no-one I know of, including myself, has managed to get the thing working properly.)

Video support in Java is, unfortunately, still very lacking on the pure Java level. There was talk a while back of something called JMC (Java media components) rectifying this, but it all went a bit quiet. Hopefully it'll pick up in future; until then it's perfectly possible to support all the common platforms using native libraries.

Answer (score 4):

You can use ready-to-use `WebcamPanel` Swing components from [Webcam Capture API](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture) project (I'm the author). The project is portable and works well on 32- and 64-bit architectures of Windows, Linux, Mac OS, as well as ARM devices like e.g. Raspberry Pi (both armel and armhf).

Example code below will display image from webcam inside `JFrame` window (FPS rate is configurable):

```
JPanel panel = new WebcamPanel(Webcam.getDefault());
JFrame window = new JFrame("Test webcam capture");
window.add(panel);
window.pack();
window.setVisible(true);
window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

[image: Test webcam capture]

JARs are available in Maven Central but if you are not using Maven you can also download separate ZIP which consists of all required dependencies (all necessary 3rd-party JARs).

Answer (score 3):

JMF is a library for Java using Medias.

Java is much bigger than just a programing language, don't be afraid of using it's libraries to add functionalities.

Take a look at some examples: http://www.mutong.com/fischer/java/usbcam/ and http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/40115-capturing-video-webcam-jmf.html

Comment: As far as I can tell JMF is no longer supported, at least by Oracle/Sun. All the examples seem to be for java 1.1, the cited web page is nearly 8 years old :) The biggest downside to using JMF IMHO is the end user needs to install it on their system before you can run a Java application using it. Lastly I was never able to get JMF to run on Linux, which means it is really not cross platform.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm personally gonna stick with C++, and Python, but I still wanna learn Java. So this information is very helpful so thank you.

Comment: @Jim Morris: yep, I just mentioned JMF because the question mentioned it

Answer (score 3):

Below an implementation using [Marvin Framework](http://www.marvinproject.org). This framework provides a set of [plug-ins](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/en/plugins.html) for real time video processing.

```
package video.simpleVideoTest;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import marvin.gui.MarvinImagePanel;
import marvin.image.MarvinImage;
import marvin.video.MarvinJavaCVAdapter;
import marvin.video.MarvinVideoInterface;

public class SimpleVideoTest extends JFrame implements Runnable{

    private MarvinVideoInterface    videoAdapter;
    private MarvinImage             image;
    private MarvinImagePanel        videoPanel;

    public SimpleVideoTest(){
        super("Simple Video Test");

        // Create the VideoAdapter and connect to the camera
        videoAdapter = new MarvinJavaCVAdapter();
        videoAdapter.connect(1);

        // Create VideoPanel
        videoPanel = new MarvinImagePanel();
        add(videoPanel);

        // Start the thread for requesting the video frames 
        new Thread(this).start();

        setSize(800,600);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleVideoTest t = new SimpleVideoTest();
        t.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            // Request a video frame and set into the VideoPanel
            image = videoAdapter.getFrame();
            videoPanel.setImage(image);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Download JMF from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-142937.html)

And you can start learning the JMF framework from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html)

Answer (score -2):

You can use this using java swings.

You can find an article about this on this blog, [geekscab.com](http://www.geekscab.com)
Sorry i dont know the exact url, So you have to search the blog