# java :display videoScreen on Jframe

Tags: java, swing

I have created a simple `JFrame` for a registration form. Now I want to display the `videoScreen` on that form for capturing the image. Could someone please tell me how to do this.

Comment: What have you tried? Could you post any code you have attempted to write. We will be able to help you better if you try it yourself first.

Comment: This looks related to me http://stackoverflow.com/q/9597185/613495

Comment: I have write a simple java programe to captured a image by webcam.. it works properly..it captures image but my problem is that I want to disply that in my registration form....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display Webcam In Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821656/display-webcam-in-java)

Comment: Try using WebcamPanel from Webcam Capture API for Java (I'm the author) project: https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the following question which seems to suit what you looking for

[display-webcam-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821656/display-webcam-in-java)

Regards